# Downloading Fonts in R: 'No fontName. Skipping'

Tags: r, fonts

I'm trying to download Calibri font. R version 4.1.3 (2022-03-10).

**I've tried:**

```
library(extrafont) 

font_import(paths='C:/Windows/Fonts', prompt=FALSE)
```

**I've also tried:**

```
library(extrafont)

library(remotes)

remotes::install_version("Rttf2pt1", version = "1.3.8")

extrafont::font_import()
```

**Both give me these errors like this:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the following code worked when I downloaded [Rtools40](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/rtools40.html).

```
library(extrafont)

library(remotes)

remotes::install_version("Rttf2pt1", version = "1.3.8")

extrafont::font_import()
```